# Ajax inside a for loop executing all at once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop

Alright, so we have this code:

```
var players = '<?php echo $players ?>';
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "url...",
  data: { currentplayer: i, players: players },
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  timeout:60000,
  success: function(output){
  <?php echo write_log("output[\"message\"]", "output[\"class\"]") ?>

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url...",
    data: { currentplayer: i, players: players },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout:60000,
    success: function(output){
           <?php echo write_log("output[\"message\"]", "output[\"class\"]") ?>
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Now the problem may sound simple but I can't find a solution.

Obviously the seconds Ajax call within the success function of the first one happens after the first one is done. This is really quick as it's just a MySQL request.

Now the seconds one is a lot longer as it is a loop (foreach and while) in the PHP file. Now it fires the first request out, then the seconds and then it does the same again (loop 1 time as specified). Now it doesn't wait for the requests to finish to continue the loop.

The problem: I don't want the requests to be at the same time.
I want it like this:
Loop begin: First Ajax Call Complete -> Second Ajax Call Complete -> Loop -> Third Ajax Call Complete -> Fourth Ajax Call Complete

One after another basically.

Additionally: async: false is not an option as it freezes the browser and I need to display live feedback after every Ajax query.

Any solutions?

Comment: I don't understand what's the point of AJAX with embedded PHP...

Comment: Btw, your `i` variable is probably getting lost inside the success function, you need a closure here. The whole thing just looks wrong though. AJAX within AJAX within PHP??? I'd start from scratch with good practices, ie. separating your JS and PHP code and possibly using promises to handle those AJAX calls separately, better organized.

Comment: You can't honestly be expecting the PHP code to _not_ execute until the ajax call is made... PHP is Sever-side, your JS is client-side.

Comment: I use this code inside a modal, but if I use the PHP outside the Ajax it would just not open the modal as the modal only finished loading after the PHP is ready. And since you can't delay PHP to start executing after the document has loaded this is my only choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in a function and call the function again on the success of the 2 ajax call. Also set a global variable for the current player count which in now in the loop.

```
var players = '<?php echo $players ?>';

var global_current_player = 0;

function doAjax(current_player) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url...",
        data: { currentplayer: current_player, players: players },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout:60000,
        success: function(output){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "url...",
                data: { currentplayer: current_player, players: players },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                timeout:60000,
                success: function(output){
                    global_current_player++;
                    if (global_current_player < 2) {
                        doAjax(global_current_player);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });   
}

doAjax(global_current_player);
```

So this function is recursive and only work till the condition `global_current_player < 2`

PS : I didn't execute the function, but this logic should work.

Answer (score 0):

To fixed the above issue try to get condition in first ajax success function and put the second ajax code out site the success function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for` loop, you can use a `while` loop and increment it only when the ajax call has returned success (or error)

try:

```
    var i =0;
    execute = True
   while(i<2){
   if(execute){
      execute = False
      $.ajax({
         .. your ajax code ...
        success:function(){
           execute = True
           i++
          }
       error:function(){
        execute = True
        i++
        } 
     })
    }
  }
```

this way, your while loop will increment only when the `ajax` returns something. till then, it'll keep running for `i`'s previous value, and since `execute` is False, the ajax will only hit once

Comment: You still need a closure there to pass the proper value of `i` on each iteration, although this doesn't solve the question and you're missing semicolons, commas, and you have an implicit global variable.

Comment: you could do the same with a for loop and as @elclanrs points out you need to close over the loop variable. Moreover, there is no point in keeping that loop busy since you can use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

you could use recursion:

```
function sync(i) {
  if (i < 2) {
    $.ajax({...,
      success: function(options) {
        ...
        $.ajax({...,
          success: function(options) {
            ...
            sync(i+1);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
sync(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I controlled the execution of your AJAX requests with a True or False flag 'prevAjaxCmpltd'.

```
var players = '<?php echo $players ?>';
var i =0;
var prevAjaxCmpltd = True;
while (i < 2)
{
  if(prevAjaxCmpltd){
      i++;
      prevAjaxCmpltd = False;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "url...",
          data: { currentplayer: i, players: players },
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          timeout:60000,
          success: function(output){
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "url...",
                  data: { currentplayer: i, players: players },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  cache: false,
                  timeout:60000,
                  success: function(output){
                      prevAjaxCmpltd = True;
                  }
              });
          }
      });
    }
}
```